# Facebook access token has expired

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I need help how to handle an expired access token.
I found some things on google with php but I don't really understand what is the right way to handle this.
if the token has expired should I just relogin again? is there something else I should do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the User should log in again. Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#expiredtokens which states

> If the access token becomes invalid, the solution is to have the person log in again, at which point you will be able to make API calls on their behalf once more.